# incorrect signature

Tags: apex

```
public class OpportunityHandler {
    public static void deleteOpportunities(Set<Id> opportunityIds) {
        List<Opportunity> closedWonOpportunities = new List<Opportunity>();
        List<Opportunity> closedLostOpportunities = new List<Opportunity>();
        for (Opportunity opp : [SELECT Id, StageName, OwnerId, IsClosed, IsWon
                                FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :opportunityIds]) {
            if (opp.IsClosed) {
                if (opp.IsWon) {
                    closedWonOpportunities.add(opp);
                } else {
                    if (opp.OwnerId != UserInfo.getUserId() && !UserInfo.isAdminUser()) {
                        throw new CustomException('Only the owner or an admin can delete a closed lost opportunity.');
                    }
                    closedLostOpportunities.add(opp);
                }
            }
        }
        if (!closedWonOpportunities.isEmpty()) {
            List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
            for (Opportunity opp : closedWonOpportunities) {
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                email.setToAddresses(new List<String>{opp.Owner.Email});
                email.setSubject('Opportunity Closed Won: ' + opp.Name);
                email.setPlainTextBody('Dear ' + opp.Owner.Name + ',\n\nThe opportunity ' + opp.Name + ' has been closed won.\n\nBest regards,\nYour Salesforce Admin');
                emails.add(email);
            }
            Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
        }
        if (!closedLostOpportunities.isEmpty()) {
            delete closedLostOpportunities;
        }
    }
}
//Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void isAdminUser() from the type System.UserInfo
```

Comment: This error is very straightforward. I've downvoted because there is no evidence of you doing research before asking this question. See the [documentation on the UserInfo class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm) and you will notice there is no `isAdminUser()` method.

Answer (score 1):

`UserInfo.isAdminUser` is not a standard method for [UserInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm). You'll need to check for a different permission or check the user's profile. For example:

```
Id profileAdminId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Admin' LIMIT 1].Id;
for (Opportunity opp : [SELECT Id, StageName, OwnerId, IsClosed, IsWon
                            FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :opportunityIds]) {
  // other code here
  if(opp.OwnerId != UserInfo.getUserId() && !profileAdminId != UserInfo.getProfileId()) {
    Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).addError('Only the owner of the opportunity, or an admin, can delete a closed lost opportunity.');
```

Notice the use of `addError`, instead of throwing an exception, which would roll back the entire transaction rather than allowing a partial save.